# How can i group together multiple entity error messages into 1 (Symfony 6)

Tags: symfony, twig

I started learning Symfony yesterday, and I got stuck to the point that I had a two-hour argument with ChatGPT, which only made it worse and worse.

form:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Conctact Us!
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="formbg bg-light rounded-4 mx-auto p-5">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="display-6 fw-normal mt-2 mb-4">Contact us</h1>
            <div class="col-5">
                {{ form_start(form) }}

                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {% if form_errors(form) %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {% for error in form_errors(form) %}
                            {{ error.message }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light w-100 fs-5 pt mt-3 p-2 rounded-4">Send</button>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

custom form theme:

```
{# form_theme.html.twig #}
{% block form_errors %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this article "Customizing form rendering" on Symfony.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html